# Get Data from db using React native and Axios

Tags: react-native, axios, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to fetch data from API on my localhost server using "Axios" in React Native but data in not fetching from API and nothing displaying.If you asking is the http request works in Server side yeah Thats working. Any comment and idea would be very much appreciated :)

**http.common :**

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:19002/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  }
});
```

**Card.js :**

```
import dataAPI from '../http/http.common'


function Card() {
  

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataFromAPI()
    }, [])


    function getDataFromAPI() {
        dataAPI.get('/latest')
            .then(async function (response) {
              setItems(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    if (!items) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <FlatGrid
        itemDimension={130}
        data={items}
        style={styles.gridView}
     
        spacing={10}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
         <TextCard item= {item} />
        )}
      />
      
    );
  }
```

**TextCard.js**

```
const TextCard = ({item }) => {
    console.log(item)
    return (
        <>
        <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: '#fff' }]}>
            <Image style={styles.itemImg} source={require('../assets/temperature.png')} />
            <Text style={styles.itemName}>Température</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemCode}>{item.Temperature} </Text>
            
          </View>
       
        
       
          </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using FlatList instead of FlatGrid?

Comment: Yeah I tried the FlatList but I have the same problem

Comment: Try passing extraData={{length: items.length}} as a prop to the FlatList and see if it solves the issue

Comment: Why you add `async` function in `then`?? It's not necessary! Add `console.log` in `then` section and show us the response! If the response is come from server, your problem in render function or in your setItems hook! you can check the items changes with this: `useEffect(() => console.log(items), [items])`

Comment: the console log doesnt show nothing I think I have a problem in the server side even I test the req using postman & thats working !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `extraData={{length: items.length}}` as a prop to the `FlatList`

And to make sure that the state is updated, add the following hook to the `Card` component

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(`There are ${items.length} items in the state right now`)
}, [items.length])
```

Let me know if its resolved, if not I'll have to replicate the issue and see where it stems from

Comment: I tried this but I still faced the same issue by the way the request return just the latest record

Comment: You tried passing extraData or using useEffect or both? also a few question for clarification,
Is response.data an array that contains only the latest record or an object that is the latest record?
Is there a reason for then chain on the get function to be an asynchronous function?
When you put a console.log inside then chain does it log the data received from the API?
Have you tried this on both iOS and Android? because I have faced this issue before on iOS where async calls stop executing after a network request..

Comment: I added exxtraData on the FlatList and I updated the useEffect, the response data in server side is an object as latest record. I'm working on Android app

Comment: So you're using an object in the data prop of FlatList instead of an array, which doesn't work, try setting the state like this instead

setItems([response.data])

Comment: its Still Not working :/

Comment: Can you show me the exact data you're getting in response.data? I'll try to replicate the issue from my end